# XGBoost converging on high depth and child weight

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, xgboost, hyperparameters

I'm using XGBoost for a time series forecasting problem. I've been performing gridsearch with time series cross validation. Oddly, the gridsearch is repeatedly converging on a high number of trees and minimum child weight.

Here's my code

```
scaler = StandardScaler()

X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)

tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=3, max_train_size = 1500)

model = xgboost.XGBRegressor()

grid_search = GridSearchCV(model,
                    param_grid = param_grid,
                    cv = tscv.split(X_scaled),
                    n_jobs = -1,
                    scoring = 'explained_variance',
                    verbose=True)

grid_search.fit(X_scaled, y)

print (grid_search.best_params_)
```

My parameter grid is

```
param_grid = {'learning_rate': [0.01, 0.1], 
          'max_depth': [4,8,12],
          'min_child_weight': [3,5,10,20,35,50],
          'subsample': [0.5, 0.75],
          'colsample_bytree': [0.5, 0.75],
          'n_estimators': [100, 300],
}
```

The gridsearch converges on

```
{'colsample_bytree': 0.5, 'learning_rate': 0.01, 'max_depth': 12, 'min_child_weight': 50, 'n_estimators': 300, 'subsample': 0.5}
```

Are there any clear reasons as to why the tree depth and min child weight are both so high? Unfortunately I cannot release my dataset. I'm just looking for general reasons as to why this might be occuring, and if the converged parameters are reasonable.

Comment: Care to explain exactly *why* this is odd, and why you consider these specific values as "high"?

Comment: From all posts I've read (https://cambridgespark.com/content/tutorials/hyperparameter-tuning-in-xgboost/index.html) (https://www.kaggle.com/tilii7/hyperparameter-grid-search-with-xgboost), the minimum child weight usually between 1 and 10. The same goes for the max depth of the tree. Perhaps I've been mislead? The found parameters are also quite a bit different from the default parameters for XGBoost (https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html).

Comment: I think you are over-interpreting the results of these posts (and why a `max_depth` value of 9 in the first post is OK, while your 12 is "oddly high"?); in any case, these parameters are highly dataset-specific (even the values between these 2 posts cover a rather great range)...

Comment: Ah, yes I think the max depth is not too much out of the norm (you're correct), but the min child weight (50) is quite a bit higher than anything I've seen. Any thoughts on the min child weight specifically?

Comment: Nope, and I think your question is marginally off-topic for SO (you don't seem to have a *coding* issue)...

Comment: Just notice that such high values of these parameters in the posts you link were not even *included* in the grid search, to start with (I mean, it is not that such high values were *tested* and found not-optimal); what could have happened if they were included...?? You could try re-running the Kaggle kernel with your own grid search, to see what may happen...

Comment: Hmm. That seems reasonable. I guess the question then becomes what is the meaning behind a very high minimum child weight. I apologize for the off-topic question - could you refer me to where I should've posted it?

Comment: In theory, the appropriate forums are [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) and [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/), but I highly doubt that you will get any meaningful answer even there, since your question is also too vague, plus it touches on interpretation issues, which is still a hot topic of current research...